# DocuSign: get the status of a specific email

Tags: docusignapi

I am doing the `docusign API` integration in my app. Right now I am getting my all envelopes details whether the user/email have completed the form or not, by checking the status.

I want help that whether it is possible to get the current session information like I have redirect the user to its `docusign` tab but what if he have left there and did not complete the process?.

One solution is to check all the statuses based on the dates and checking the latest date-time envelope status.

```
<?php

   // getting all envelops of account -> acountID
   function getAllEnvelopes(){
       $email = "myemail";
       $password = "****";
       $integratorKey = "my key";

       $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{acountid}/envelopes?from_date=3/3/2018";

       $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

       $curl = curl_init($url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
       $json_response = curl_exec($curl);



       return $json_response;

   }

 $res = getAllEnvelopes();

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($res);

?>
```

Comment: Add more details. For example, which methods you have tried, what the outcomes were.

Comment: @baileyrt let me add the question!

Comment: @baileyrt i have edited the question!

Comment: Is your overall intent to be notified when a recipient completes signing? If so, DocuSign has Connect (webhooks) that will achieve this for you.

Comment: but in the case of webhook you have to make powerforms and all the stuff on your own. Like in my case i have a powerform available in the docusign which is feed to the signer.

Comment: also everytime the powerform will be created for every email/user in the case of webhooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not so clear. You can use either account-level Connect or per-envelope Connect (the `eventNotification`) object to be notified when:

- A recipient (signer) has been sent the email asking them to sign.
- A recipient has completed signing.

At this time, you are not notified if they have started the signing ceremony but then abandoned it.

If you decide to use embedded signing and manage the signing ceremony from your application's web site then you know when the signer has started to sign since they would need to push a `Sign` button on your web site to start the signing ceremony. You can also use the `pingURL` (see the [docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/)) to be notified that the signer is still using the signing ceremony.

You mentioned PowerForms. Why? If you're using the API then usually you don't also use PowerForms.

**Added** If you have the envelopeIDs and want to know if they've been signed or not, you have two options:

1. Poll the DocuSign platform. This solution is not recommended. You can only poll once every 15 minutes or less often.
2. Create webhook using a Connect account-wide subscription. Your application will be notified anytime any envelope sent from your account is signed. Just ignore the notifications that are about envelopes you don't care about. Connect is not included with all DocuSign pricing plans, but is included with many of them. Many many DocuSign customers use Connect.

Comment: Hi Larry! Thanks for your response. Actually i want to know the signing status only i have my env ID's which are created by that user not through my application but through the docusign itself. but in my application i have got the envolope ID's created by that user on a particular power form. To check a status constantly i have to loop through the all the ids statuses whether the user have completed or not ?

Comment: @programmer -- I've added to my answer

Comment: ok so i think webhook is better but in this case i have to use all the procedure through webhook? i mean what if i only want to check the status and all the rest i am doing with the rest API?

Comment: You can use the notification message sent via the webhook as the trigger for your software to then make additional calls via the API. That's a common pattern. "Polling" is when you repeatedly call API methods, looking for a change in status.

Comment: sorry i did not understand. My question is to check the status whether a document is completed signing or not ?

Comment: To find out if an envelope is complete (signed by everyone) use either Connect or polling, as I describe in the answer. Connect is preferred. If you are creating the envelopes via the api you can also create a per-envelope Connect subscription via the `eventNotification` object in the Envelopes: create request object.

Comment: Thank you @larry so i conclude that i should use webhook to make all of the procedure of my own.